# Automatically define username and password for mysqli depending on server type. Good idea?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've created a page to include with all my connections that will automatically set my sql username and password, as well as error reporting settings, depending on whether the connection is being made with the testing server or the live site. Wondering if this is a good idea? Why or why not? Am I just being lazy or is there a better way of doing this?

```
<?php 
# This will set username and password for database access, as well as error reporting according to the server being used.

# It eliminates the need to change code when switching from testing environment to live site.

# Let's find out which server is being used and take the first 3 characters of the server name.

$thisServer = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, 3);

# If on localhost (testing server):
if($thisServer == 'loc'){

# enable php error reporting
error_reporting(-1); 

# enable mysqli reporting
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;

# set username and password
$dbHost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbUserName = 'myUser'; 
$dbPassword = 'myPassword'; 

# If on remote server:
} elseif($thisServer == 'www') { # <-- This should be first 3 characters you see in URL of live site.

# disable php error reporting
error_reporting(0);

# disable mysqli reporting
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF;

# set username and password
$dbHost = 'mysite.com';
$dbUserName = 'myUser'; 
$dbPassword = 'myPassword'; 
};
?>
```

Comment: I think this is quite clever. Can't see any real issues with it - though maybe in your final production build you should remove the unneeded bit.

Comment: Personally, I'd add a better check for what environment the code is running in. Have you considered that the user may access your site either via "yoursite.com" without the "www" at the start?

Comment: Both good points. Thanks! I suppose I could do this to set vars ONLY IF NOT on the testing server. Would solve both issues and use about half the code! Thanks again!

Comment: Things would be cleaner if you use a separate file for each environment's settings, and just include the correct one from your main (common) settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Apache, I expect Nginx could handle similar functionality. You presumably have different virtual hosts on your web server for production and development environments. You can have the web server set the desired variables for you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    SetEnv DB_HOST    "localhost"
    SetEnv DB_USER    "myUser"
    SetEnv DB_PASS    "myPassword"
    SetEnv DB_REPORT  "0"
    SetEnv ERR_REPORTING "0"
    ....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    SetEnv DB_HOST    "localhost"
    SetEnv DB_USER    "testUser"
    SetEnv DB_PASS    "testPassword"
    SetEnv DB_REPORT  "255"
    SetEnv ERR_REPORTING "-1"
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, in your PHP code you can retrieve them. Same code for both servers, nice and neat.

```
$dbHost = getenv("DB_HOST");
$dbUserName = getenv("DB_USER");
$dbPassword = getenv("DB_PASS");
$dbReporting = (int)getenv("DB_REPORT");
$errLevel = (int)getenv("ERR_REPORTING");

$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = $dbReporting;
error_reporting($errLevel);
```

Another advantage of this approach is the isolation of database credentials from people who don't need them.

Comment: 1. Where would I enter this code? Would I create a new php page for this and include it, and if so, how often would I need to include it, or is it something I need to set on the server somehow? Sorry, I'm pretty new to all this.


2. Would DB_REPORT turn off all php errors or just database related stuff? 


3. Could I name other vars using the "DB_" prefix, like DB_WHATEVER, to isolate other variables I may want to isolate?

Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: It's not code, it's setup on your web server. Apache defines the environment variables inside each virtual host, and you can access them from PHP. Names are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use localhost or network ip if you will work on local network.

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "192.168.1.1") {
  //your local codes
}
```